# Need helps in coding (text minimized)

Tags: r, element

I posted a question about coding few days ago ([Need help code mock sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545906/need-help-code-mock-sampling)).  I noticed there may be too much context.  Thus, extending from the post, I minimize my question.  Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

I have random number like this:

```
pass.theo <- c(2,4,12,13,14,19,21,27,30,31,32,35,36,38,41,44,49,50,52,57,59,60,61,63,65,68,79,80,86,92,96,100)
```

Beginning of the first number (i.e., 2) in this particular case, I would like to find  a number that is the first number that is 5 or greater than previous elements (i.e., 2).  In this case, the number is 12.  And then from the number 12, I want to find another first number that is 5 or greater than and continue until the end.   With the number above, I manually generated this code but need code for conducting in general.

```
tf <- c(
pass.theo[2]-pass.theo[1] > 5,  #
pass.theo[3]-pass.theo[1] > 5, # select
pass.theo[4]-pass.theo[3] > 5, #
pass.theo[5]-pass.theo[3] > 5, #
pass.theo[6]-pass.theo[3] > 5, # select
pass.theo[7]-pass.theo[6] > 5, #
pass.theo[8]-pass.theo[6] > 5, # select
pass.theo[9]-pass.theo[8] > 5,
pass.theo[10]-pass.theo[8] > 5,
pass.theo[11]-pass.theo[8] > 5,
pass.theo[12]-pass.theo[8] > 5, # select
pass.theo[13]-pass.theo[12] > 5,
pass.theo[14]-pass.theo[12] > 5,
pass.theo[15]-pass.theo[12] > 5, # select
pass.theo[16]-pass.theo[15] > 5,
pass.theo[17]-pass.theo[15] > 5, # select
pass.theo[18]-pass.theo[17] > 5,
pass.theo[19]-pass.theo[17] > 5,
pass.theo[20]-pass.theo[17] > 5, # select
pass.theo[21]-pass.theo[20] > 5, 
pass.theo[22]-pass.theo[20] > 5,
pass.theo[23]-pass.theo[20] > 5,
pass.theo[24]-pass.theo[20] > 5, # select
pass.theo[25]-pass.theo[24] > 5,
pass.theo[26]-pass.theo[24] > 5,
pass.theo[27]-pass.theo[24] > 5, # select
pass.theo[28]-pass.theo[27] > 5,
pass.theo[29]-pass.theo[27] > 5, # select
pass.theo[30]-pass.theo[29] > 5, # select
pass.theo[31]-pass.theo[30] > 5,
pass.theo[32]-pass.theo[30] > 5 # select
)
tf
passes <- c(pass.theo[1], pass.theo[-1][tf])

expected.select <- ifelse(pass.theo %in% passes, 'select', 'drop') 
cbind(pass.theo, expected.select)
      pass.theo expected.select
# [1,] "2"       "select"       
# [2,] "4"       "drop"         
# [3,] "12"      "select"       
# [4,] "13"      "drop"         
# [5,] "14"      "drop"         
# [6,] "19"      "select"       
# [7,] "21"      "drop"         
# [8,] "27"      "select"       
# [9,] "30"      "drop"         
#[10,] "31"      "drop"         
#[11,] "32"      "drop"         
#[12,] "35"      "select"       
#[13,] "36"      "drop"         
#[14,] "38"      "drop"         
#[15,] "41"      "select"       
#[16,] "44"      "drop"         
#[17,] "49"      "select"       
#[18,] "50"      "drop"         
#[19,] "52"      "drop"         
#[20,] "57"      "select"       
#[21,] "59"      "drop"         
#[22,] "60"      "drop"         
#[23,] "61"      "drop"         
#[24,] "63"      "select"       
#[25,] "65"      "drop"         
#[26,] "68"      "drop"         
#[27,] "79"      "select"       
#[28,] "80"      "drop"         
#[29,] "86"      "select"       
#[30,] "92"      "select"       
#[31,] "96"      "drop"         
#[32,] "100"     "select"
```

I want to include first element always and select tf==TRUE from the rest of pass.theo.

```
passes
```

Is there a way to make a function above?

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: *"find numbers that are 5 or greater than previous elements"* would simply be `diff(pass.theo) > 5`, but that does not match your code. Sounds like your logic is a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: So it appears the the index being subtracted changes when a calculation returns TRUE.

Comment: Thanks for comments.  I tried to clarify more above.  For example, if I find a first number (i.e., 12) that is 5 or greater than the number, 2.  Then, I want to repeat it from the number, 12 so that the next number is 19 and so forth.

Comment: It is too complicated for me...  I really need helps for this.

Comment: Is `pass.theo[29]-pass.theo[28] > 5, # select` correct? Shouldn't it read `pass.theo[29]-pass.theo[27] > 5, # select`, since the previous iteration is not TRUE?

Comment: Hi Oliver.  Yes, you are right.  It is typo.

Comment: Corrected.  Thanks for pointing out!!!

Comment: I added expected selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pass.theo <- c(2,4,12,13,14,19,21,27,30,31,32,35,36,38,41,44,49,50,52,57,59,60,61,63,65,68,79,80,86,92,96,100)
# to keep the original pass.theo untouched
dat <- pass.theo
for (i in seq_along(pass.theo)[-1]) {
  if ( (dat[i] - dat[i-1]) < 5 ) dat[i] <- dat[i-1]
}
ret <- c(FALSE, diff(dat) >= 5)
```

For demonstration, I'll bind them so you can see what happened:

```
data.frame(pass.theo = pass.theo, mod = dat, ret = ret)
#    pass.theo mod   ret
# 1          2   2 FALSE
# 2          4   2 FALSE
# 3         12  12  TRUE
# 4         13  12 FALSE
# 5         14  12 FALSE
# 6         19  19  TRUE
# 7         21  19 FALSE
# 8         27  27  TRUE
# 9         30  27 FALSE
# 10        31  27 FALSE
# 11        32  32  TRUE
# 12        35  32 FALSE
# 13        36  32 FALSE
# 14        38  38  TRUE
# 15        41  38 FALSE
# 16        44  44  TRUE
# 17        49  49  TRUE
# 18        50  49 FALSE
# 19        52  49 FALSE
# 20        57  57  TRUE
# 21        59  57 FALSE
# 22        60  57 FALSE
# 23        61  57 FALSE
# 24        63  63  TRUE
# 25        65  63 FALSE
# 26        68  68  TRUE
# 27        79  79  TRUE
# 28        80  79 FALSE
# 29        86  86  TRUE
# 30        92  92  TRUE
# 31        96  92 FALSE
# 32       100 100  TRUE
```

I'm not a fan of iteratively changing the vector like this, but I don't know of other tools that roll along the vector correctly.

**Edit:**

Actually, taking inspiration from @MrFlick's `Reduce` (should have thought of that), you can replace the `for` loop with:

```
dat2 <- Reduce(function(a,b) if ((b-a)<5) a else b,
               pass.theo, accumulate = TRUE)
```

Then

```
c(FALSE, diff(dat2) >= 5)
```

is the same as my `ret` above. (I'm not trying to steal @MrFlick's answer, he should take credit for suggesting `Reduce` over my sloppy/inefficient `for` loop.

Comment: You really cleaned up the Reduce call so I totally approve.

Comment: I often lean towards `zoo::rollapply` initially for something like, but it does not *accumulate* as I would hope. I feel like `Reduce(...,accumulate=TRUE)` is so much an under-appreciated rolling function with that argument. (The fact that `Reduce` is doing a `for` loop under the hood is a technicality I'll have to accept :-)

Comment: Hi r2evans.  This is great!!!  I will have to spend time to understand your code though.  Thank you very much for your helps and all others for comments!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method using `Reduce()`

```
pp<-which(sapply(Reduce(function(a,b) {
    aa <- a[[1]]
    if (b-aa>5) {
        return(list(b, T))
    } else {
       return(list(aa, F))
    }
}, pass.theo, init=list(pass.theo[1],F), accumulate=T), `[[`, 2)) - 1
passes <- c(pass.theo[1], pass.theo[pp])
```

Basically I used `Reduce()` to step pairwise through the elements while passing along the current lowest value. I then use `sapply()` to extract the values where a change occurred and use `which()` to get the indexes (subtracting 1 because I used an initial value in the `Reduce` call).